# How to generate executable file that can run on both Unix and Linux?

Tags: c++, c, g++

I am using g++(under linux) to compile a piece of c code. The compiled executable file works good on linux. But it doesn`t run on unix(SunOS). How to make the compiled file runs on both Unix and Linux? Thank you.

Comment: Unless there is a Linux emulator on SunOS, you can't. They are not binary compatible.

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=run+linux+binary+on+solaris

Comment: @RSahu is it possible to have a C++ intermediate byte-code?

Comment: There no longer is a single "UNIX" system, rather there is a large family of UNIX and UNIX-like systems. For example, in the UNIX family we have the BSD variants, Solaris (SunOS has been dead and buried for more than a decade), and even Mac OSX. Of the UNIX-like systems the most well-know is Linux, of which there are hundred of variants. So as you can see there no single "UNIX" system.

Comment: Also then there's the underlying hardware platform. Old SunOS ran only on SPARC systems, the BSDs can run on many different platforms. OSX used to be PowerPC only, but went 32-bit x86 and now is limited to 64-bit x86. And the Linuxes runs on hundreds of platforms and processor combinations.

Comment: All in all, just because you can compiler a C or C++ program on one "UNIX-y" platform doesn't mean it will be able to run on another.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

It is not only the binary generation, your linker will link libraries that your system uses. This will vary on different linux distributions already! If you really want to create a platform independent binary use Java or compile your C++ program using llvm.
When you compile C code to llvm bytecode it can be interpreted with lli. You can supply lli with all the native .so files you need and it will be able to execute the code. I was quite satisfied with the results.

Comment: Thank you Clambake and all the other repliers.

Comment: Please do not do this. lli code is highly platform-dependant as it does not abstract away from the layout of kernel data-structures such as `struct stat`. Even in the unlikely case that your code manages to run on the target platform, it will likely crash the instant you try to do something complicated like opening a file with `open(2)`, as the order of the flag-bits is platform-dependant.

Answer (score 4):

The POSIX.1 standard guarantees compatibility on source code niveau. This is—every program that is written to use the POSIX.1 APIs is guaranteed to compile and run on any POSIX platform. POSIX does not and did never guarantee that binaries are portable between different platforms, even if all of them are compliant.

Do not assume that you can execute the same binary on different platforms. While there are some toolkits that provide varying levels of emulation, this doesn't alway work.

For the special case of executing Linux binaries, there are some solutions, like lxrun for Solaris or the builtin system-call translation-layer the maps Linux to FreeBSD system calls on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3):

[lxrun](http://www.sco.com/skunkware/emulators/#lxrun) is a utility that allows Linux binaries to run on a variety of other Unix-like platforms, including Solaris.